# How do we know when all validation has passed using Bootstrap forms styles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

From official Bootstrap Forms, under [custom styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles), how do we know when **all** validation has passed?

I tried to test it by putting alert in several places but I can still see the alert when before all the validation pass.

```
<script>
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                        alert('done 1')
                    }, false);
                    alert('done 2')
                });
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Are all fields you expect to validate have 'from-control' class already? Please provide HTML as well.